# python datetime.timedelta not adding hour

Tags: python

after reading the description, I am confused that this

```
import datetime
d = datetime.date.today()
print datetime.timedelta(hours = 9)
print d
d += datetime.timedelta(hours = 9)
print datetime.datetime.strftime(d, '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S')
```

is printing

```
9:00:00
2014-08-05
08/05/2014 00:00:00
```

I just can't see what mistake I am making here. What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`d` is a `datetime.date`, not a `datetime.datetime` hence adding a `timedelta` less than 24 hours has no affect. Change

```
d = datetime.date.today()
```

to

```
d = datetime.datetime.today()
```